# Chat FAQ multiple lines of text in a message

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I struggled to work out how to write multi-line messages in chat (I can't remember where I learnt it, but I can't find it in the Chat FAQ).  It would've been easier if I had read something like this in the Chat FAQ:

- To write a multi-line message press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> at the end of the line.

This could appear in one of the following sections:

- [How do I talk?](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/faq#talk)
- [How do I format my messages?](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/faq#formatting)

Should this be included in the Chat FAQ? Which section should it be included in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if it is a feature that many people use but if it should be added to the Chat FAQ at all then to the [*How do I format my messages?*](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#formatting) section.